# Change the multiple choice list item checkbox tint

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, android-styles

I have an android application, in it I have a list view with choice mode set to ***multiple***. I have set the layout to *simple_list_item_multiple_choice*. It gives the checkboxes at the right side of the row.

But here's the problem: button tint of these checkboxes is terrible blue (which is far from my application color scheme). Whatever I do, I can't change it.

I have already tried: creating a style for CheckBox and creating a style for CheckedTextView, changing there all kinds of button tints and color accents.

None of it works. 
What should I do?

A piece of layout:

```
...
   <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" /> ...
```

A piece of activity code:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, players);
  itemsList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Solutions I've tried:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/MainColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/MainColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/MainColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/MainColor</item>
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxStyle</item>
    <item name="android:checkedTextViewStyle">@style/CheckedTextViewStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="CheckBoxStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="CheckedTextViewStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:checkMarkTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

UPD: Also, if someone knows how to implement this without checkboxes, but also without creating a useless custom adapter, I would accept this as an answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with Android `Lollipop` (Api 21) you can set [`checkMarkTint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#checkMarkTint) to your activity's theme:

```
<item name="android:checkMarkTint">#ff0000</item>
```

To control the `checkMark`'s color.

If you only want to do this for this specific adapter, then create a new theme, extending your activity's theme:

```
<style name="AdapterTheme" parent="@style/MainTheme">
    <item name="android:checkMarkTint">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

And set it to your `ArrayAdapter`:

```
ContextThemeWrapper themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AdapterTheme);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(themedContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, players);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create three drawables:

**checkbox_selector.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

**btn_check_on.xml**

```
<vector android:height="32dp" android:viewportHeight="105.0"
    android:viewportWidth="105.0" android:width="32dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@color/colorAccent" android:pathData="M48,17c-17.12,0 -31,13.88 -31,31s13.88,31 31,31S79,65.12 79,48S65.12,17 48,17zM43.74,59.84L32.31,48.55l3.23,-3.19l8.2,8.1l17.34,-17.13l3.23,3.19L43.74,59.84z"/>
</vector>
```

**btn_check_off.xml**

```
<vector android:height="32dp" android:viewportHeight="105.0"
    android:viewportWidth="105.0" android:width="32dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#fafafa" android:pathData="M48,17c-17.12,0 -31,13.88 -31,31s13.88,31 31,31S79,65.12 79,48S65.12,17 48,17zM48,75.55c-15.21,0 -27.55,-12.33 -27.55,-27.55c0,-15.21 12.33,-27.55 27.55,-27.55c15.21,0 27.55,12.33 27.55,27.55C75.55,63.21 63.21,75.55 48,75.55z"/>
</vector>
```

Apply **checkbox_selector.xml** as drawable to your checkbox. You will get the desired result

Comment: But how do I apply custom drawables to checkbox in a default android row layout? I suppose it involves creating a whole custom adapter, which I am trying to avoid :(